# How can I show error message after select photo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with my component InputAvatar - https://codesandbox.io/s/721n5346x6

How Can I show error message after select photo, if size of photo is not 200x200 px?

I think that problem is with  img.onload = function(), because error message is not returned in time.

Thank you advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the `onload` does not return in time. This is an asynchronous event callback, so it fires only after the image finishes loading. This results in an empty array value returned from `getErrors`, because it is executed sooner than the image loads.

In order to make the code work, you'll have to introduce some async aware code, eg. using promises.

```
getErrors(value = this.state.file || "") {
  // Return a single promise and move the function execution inside.
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const errors = []
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = value;
    img.onload = function() {
      var w = img.width;
      var h = img.height;

      errors.push("error");
      if (w != 200 || h != 200) {
        errors.push("The photo must be 200 x 200 px.");
      }
      // Resolve the pending promise with the errors value letting callers know it's ready.
      resolve(errors)
    };
  })
}
```

This way you'll be able to wait for the outcome of the image loading and use it in a way you need it.

```
validate(value = this.state.file || "") {
  this.getErrors(value)
    // Wait for the errors and only then set the state.
    .then(errors => 
      this.setState({
        errors
      });
    )
}
```